# Alinhamento de Listas

Tags: html

Como eu faço pra deixar uma lista alinhada lado a lado e ao centro? já criei alguns tipos de listas porém no meu computador ela fica certinho, mas em outras fica sempre torto!

segue o código de exemplo:

```
<ul>
<li> <img width="120px" src="_imagens/ef-1.png"/> <br> <p> texto </p> </li>
<li> <img width="120px" src="_imagens/ef-2.png"/> <br> <p> texto </p> </li>
<li> <img width="120px" src="_imagens/ef-3.png"/> <br> <p> texto </p> </li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso o resultado abaixo seja o que você espera, pode adicionar o elemento `div` no **HTML** com a classe `myClass`, colocar o `text-aling: center` na `div` e colocar o `display: inline-block` nos itens da lista `li` no **CSS**.

```css
.myClass li{
  display: inline-block;
}

.myClass {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
<ul>
<li> <img width="120px" src="_imagens/ef-1.png"/> <br> <p> texto </p> </li>
<li> <img width="120px" src="_imagens/ef-2.png"/> <br> <p> texto </p> </li>
<li> <img width="120px" src="_imagens/ef-3.png"/> <br> <p> texto </p> </li>  
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Nossa, tão simples! Obrigado pela ajuda, tenha uma boa tarde!

Comment: Que bom Fábio, aceite a resposta. Veja como fazendo uma tour: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour